# How to hide specific column header in a list WebPart?

Tags: column

I created a webpart with URL column header, but i want to hide it for users...i know i can hide it using CSS but it hides all the colum headers in other webparts, Any solution to hide only the URL column header? Please Help, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you need to go through the tree, if that makes any sense?

so if you have id as follows

```
webpart -> table -> button
```

you would do the css the same to target the webpart with specific id only!

```
#webpart .table tr td .button
```

The first part is to get to the nearest unique id, ids need to be unique and you wont find them anywhere else, I said webpart id as its a safe bet it will be unique! but then you need to go down the tree of class names to the control you want changing!

any other way? yes if you create the webpart yourself and say you have a custom list using splistview it would create a table format in css that would be used thoughout the page... to get around this i would encapsulate it within a div and give the div a unique id that i can call and manipulate accordingly by the method above!

somthing similar someone asked a question is how you want to do it.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9020190/how-to-target-and-style-specific-elements-using-css